# Take contents of a file, convert them to a single line and append them to the original file Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, file

I'm working on solving a task that requires that I open a text file in Python. The file has 3 lines:

```
Moose
Chases
Car
```

I need to read that file, then append the three words concatenated on the 4th line. So, the modified text file would contain:

```
Moose
Chases
Car
Moose Chases Car
```

I'm new to working with files, so I am not sure why what I am doing is not modifying the file.

```
def func(value):
    return ''.join(value.splitlines())

f = open("WordTextFile1.txt", "a+")
myString = f.read()
new_str = func(myString)
f.write(new_str)
f.close
```

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What happens if you actually call `f.close`?

Comment: use the `with` statement to open files, it closes files automatically

Comment: You're missing the `()` after `f.close`.

Comment: `''.join` should be `' '.join` to put a space between the words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
def func(value):
    return  '\n' + ' '.join(value.splitlines()) 

with open("abc.txt", "r+") as f:
    data = func(f.read())
    
    f.write(data)
```

---

When you read the file in the `a+` mode, it actually returns nothing.

---

Or you can seek to the start of file before reading it. when using `a+` mode.

```
def func(value):
    return  '\n' + ' '.join(value.splitlines()) 

with open("abc.txt", "a+") as f:
    f.seek(0)
    data = func(f.read())
    f.write(data)
```

Comment: It's not that `'a+'` returns nothing, but the file object is at the end of the file already

Comment: @Samples Welcome. Bruh

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code

> You've to open the file in wither `r+` or `w+` mode in order to do both read and write operation on a file.

```
with open('asfa.txt', 'r+') as file:
    lines = file.read().splitlines()
    string = ' '.join(lines)
    file.write('\n' + string)
```

**output**

```
Moose
Chases
Car
Moose Chases Car
```